# Why does e.Handled = true not stop key processing in this case?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have this code. When I hit Enter when `toolFolderName` (a toolbar textbox) has focus, the Enter key is processed fine. Then, despite the `e.Handled = true;` the `filesDataGridView_KeyUp` event fires. Curiously (or maybe not, you decide), if I set a breakpoint in `toolFolderName_KeyPress`, and hit Continue when execution breaks, without doing anything else, the keystroke does not propagate to the DGV event.

I realize I'm using both `KeyUp` and `KeyPress` events. Does `e.Handled` not work across those events? I want a toolbar textbox and a DGV on the same form to use the Enter key, each for its own purposes. What approach should I take?

```
private void toolFolderName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Keys)e.KeyChar == Keys.Return)
    {
         // code
         // code
         e.Handled = true;//does this not mean "Hey, every control on this form,
                          //ignore this keystroke, it has been handled?"
    }
}

private void filesDataGridView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // receives Enter key despite e.Handled in toolFolderName_KeyPress
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
        // processing code
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.Handled` only applies to this very event. If you want to suppress processing of KeyUp as well, you must use the same logic in the KeyUp handler or set a flag (most likely a `bool`) in the KeyDown handler that tells the KeyUp handler to ignore its KeyUp event as well.

Comment: Thanks, but can you clarify? Both events have e.Handled, so which event do you mean it only applies to? Also, I don't want to supress the KeyUp handle. I only want to supress it when the DGV control doesn't have focus and thus has no business processing the key. Why does it even receive the keystroke?

Comment: `KeyDown => e.SuppressKeyPress = true`. Setting this to `true` also sets `e.Handled = true`. `e.Handled` doesn't suppress the key pressed, it just prevents the event from being passed on to the underlying Control.

Comment: @Jim unfortunately, the keystroke goes from the `KeyPress` event to the `KeyDown` event (in different controls). `SuppressKeyPress` is a `KeyDown` property, so by the time I _can_ set it, it's too late. I wanted the `KeyDown` event not to fire at all.

Comment: `KeyPress` is raised after `KeyDown`. Setting `e.SuppressKeyPress = true` in `KeyDown`, you suppress the key pressed and so the `KeyPress` event. Not `KeyUp`, that's another thing.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks but I think I'm not explaining right. There's a textbox and it has focus. I type something in and hit Enter. `toolFolderName_KeyPress` fires and its code executes, ending with `e.Handled = true;` So far so good. Then `filesDataGridView_KeyUp` fires even though the DGV doesn't have focus, and even though I had set `e.Handled = true;` I want `filesDataGridView_KeyUp` to fire _only when it has focus_ and the user lets up on a pressed key. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I don't know what you mean: if you want to suppress the **Key Pressed**, you set `e.SuppressKeyPress = true` in `KeyDown` of the Control that wants to suppress the Key and thus the `KeyPress` event. `e.Handled = true` doesn't send forth (to Windows) the event for further processing. -- No idea what the `KeyUp` event of another Control has to do with this. You should show what the `// code // code` is doing. Moving Focus or causing it to move? Pressing the Enter key in a Control doesn't raise events in another without a reason.